# Get value from array of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array of n dataframes, where each dataframe contains data from one year.  I would like to be able to grab the same value from each dataframe, so that I would have n values. Is there an easy way to interact with dataframe arrays to do this?

I can loop through the array, grab the value, and store it in a separate array. But, that may be slower than performing an operation on the whole array.

Comment: What type of array are the dataframes in?  You should provide a Short example of the *data*, with *made-up* data frames (if necessary to keep it short).  You should try a solution with iteration on your example data and provide it as a *model* for what you are asking.

Comment: Any reason you don't just concatenate all these dfs? wouldn't the lookup be significantly simpler then?

Comment: Another approach would be storing them in a Panel with the 'items' axis corresponding to the year. A Panel is the 3-dimensional analogue to a DataFrame in Pandas. You could then index into major and minor axis to get a Series of the values you want.

Comment: @EdChum, that's what I ended up doing. It seems to work well.